# Adding svg to page from svg sprite

Tags: svg

I'm using grunt-svgstore in my grunt set up to create a svg sprite file from svg I add to my project.

The output is something like this.

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><symbol viewBox="0 0 32 32" id="shape-times"><title>times</title><desc>Created with Sketch.</desc> <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.4.4 (17249) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->    <g id="times-Icons" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage"> <g id="times-times" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" fill="#B7C0C7"> <path d="M17.4142136,16 L23.7764339,9.63777963 C24.1745374,9.23967616 24.1686989,8.6123497 23.7781746,8.22182541 C23.3849276,7.82857845 22.753706,7.83208044 22.3622204,8.22356607 L16,14.5857864 L9.63777963,8.22356607 C9.23967616,7.8254626 8.6123497,7.83130112 8.22182541,8.22182541 C7.82857845,8.61507236 7.83208044,9.246294 8.22356607,9.63777963 L14.5857864,16 L8.22356607,22.3622204 C7.8254626,22.7603238 7.83130112,23.3876503 8.22182541,23.7781746 C8.61507236,24.1714215 9.246294,24.1679196 9.63777963,23.7764339 L16,17.4142136 L22.3622204,23.7764339 C22.7603238,24.1745374 23.3876503,24.1686989 23.7781746,23.7781746 C24.1714215,23.3849276 24.1679196,22.753706 23.7764339,22.3622204 L17.4142136,16 L17.4142136,16 Z" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"/> </g> </g> </symbol></svg>
```

At the top of my document I'm adding a reference to the svg file.

```
    <?php include_once("images/svg/processed/svg-defs.svg"); ?>
```

Whats the best way or how do I show the svg on the page. I'm trying things like this.

```
    <object type="image/svg+xml" width="100" height="100" data="#times-Icons"></object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To can reference a `<symbol>` element with a `<use>` element.

You should include the SVG with the symbols at the top of your document.  Actually it could go anywhere, but I believe Safari has a bug which requires the definitions to be before the references to them.

You will need to hide the symbol definition SVG so it is not visible. To do that can either use `display="none"` or set `width="0" height="0"`.

Then to reference the symbol, create another SVG of the desired size with a `<use>` element.

```
<svg width="40px" height="40px">
  <use xlink:href="#shape-times"/>
</svg>
```

You can set the size explicitly as above, or use CSS as in the following example.

```css
.large {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.small {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" display="none"><symbol viewBox="0 0 32 32" id="shape-times"><title>times</title><desc>Created with Sketch.</desc> <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.4.4 (17249) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->    <g id="times-Icons" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage"> <g id="times-times" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" fill="#B7C0C7"> <path d="M17.4142136,16 L23.7764339,9.63777963 C24.1745374,9.23967616 24.1686989,8.6123497 23.7781746,8.22182541 C23.3849276,7.82857845 22.753706,7.83208044 22.3622204,8.22356607 L16,14.5857864 L9.63777963,8.22356607 C9.23967616,7.8254626 8.6123497,7.83130112 8.22182541,8.22182541 C7.82857845,8.61507236 7.83208044,9.246294 8.22356607,9.63777963 L14.5857864,16 L8.22356607,22.3622204 C7.8254626,22.7603238 7.83130112,23.3876503 8.22182541,23.7781746 C8.61507236,24.1714215 9.246294,24.1679196 9.63777963,23.7764339 L16,17.4142136 L22.3622204,23.7764339 C22.7603238,24.1745374 23.3876503,24.1686989 23.7781746,23.7781746 C24.1714215,23.3849276 24.1679196,22.753706 23.7764339,22.3622204 L17.4142136,16 L17.4142136,16 Z" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"/> </g> </g> </symbol></svg>

<svg width="40px" height="40px">
  <use xlink:href="#shape-times"/>
</svg>

<svg class="large">
  <use xlink:href="#shape-times"/>
</svg>

<svg class="small">
  <use xlink:href="#shape-times"/>
</svg>
```